# Automatically unchecking the checkbox when someone exits fullscreen using escape or f11 (JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to javascript and only know bare basics. I have an HTML checkbox which is powered by javascript to toggle and untoggle fullscreen. The problem I am facing is I don't know how to make it so if someone exits the fullscreen after toggling fullscreen using escape or f11, how do I make it so the checkbox automatically unchecks. Please provide me an exact script <3.

Here is what I have so far: https://codepen.io/SkylixMC/pen/JmJwVL

I have tried using this script with out any success:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('fullscreen');
if (el.checked == true){
document.onfullscreenchange = function ( event ) { 
  el.checked = false;
}; 
  }) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Took me a lot longer than I thought this would.
Following [this](https://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/fullscreen) I was able to work out the below:

```
elem.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange",function(){
    if (document.mozFullScreen == false) {
      document.getElementById("fullscreen").checked = false; 
    }
  }, false);

  elem.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange",function(){
      if (document.webkitIsFullScreen == false) {
        document.getElementById("fullscreen").checked = false; 
      }
  }, false);
```

[Here is a live example](https://codepen.io/tomdickson/pen/BqZMYz)

Comment: Credit where credit is due.  Good work.  Hope the person who asked the question comes back to select this as the correct answer.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me. Thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
let fullScreen = false
window.onkeydown = e =>{
    if(fullScreen & e.keyCode==122 || e.keyCode==27){
        //here you clear stuff , couse user wants to exit
            console.log("exitFullScreen")
        fullScreen = false
    }
}

window.onresize = _=> {if((screen.availHeight-70 || screen.height-70) <= window.innerHeight && "fullscreen"){
    fullScreen = true
    console.log("enteringFullScreen")
}}
```

[Live Example](https://codepen.io/D3Portillo/full/zmzeoj/)