# Unchecking the checkbox when someone exits fullscreen using escape or f11 (JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, fullscreen

A few months back I asked this same question: [Automatically unchecking the checkbox when someone exits fullscreen using escape or f11 (JAVASCRIPT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52771579/automatically-unchecking-the-checkbox-when-someone-exits-fullscreen-using-escape)

The question was answered, however, that technique no longer works on google chrome. Being the Javascript newbie I am, I can't figure this out, nor can I find an answer anywhere.

So, let me restate the question. The problem I am facing is I don't know how to make it so if someone exits the fullscreen after toggling fullscreen using escape or f11, how do I make it so the checkbox automatically unchecks. Please provide me an exact script <3.

Here is the old code I had:

```
    var el = document.getElementById('fullscreen');
if (el.checked == true){
document.onfullscreenchange = function ( event ) { 
  el.checked = false;
}; 
  }) );
```

A helpful member of this community then helped me, and told me to use this:

```
    elem.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange",function(){
    if (document.mozFullScreen == false) {
      document.getElementById("fullscreen").checked = false; 
    }
  }, false);

  elem.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange",function(){
      if (document.webkitIsFullScreen == false) {
        document.getElementById("fullscreen").checked = false; 
      }
  }, false);
```

Here is a live demonstration of what he provided: https://codepen.io/tomdickson/pen/BqZMYz

This still works on Opera, edge, and a select few browsers, but does not work on firefox and chrome. Help?

Comment: What kind of HTML markup is this? `<div id="mcmap"</div>`

Comment: mcmap is the div ID of the element I want in fullscreen if thats your question.

Comment: Please read closely character by character my comment above. Do you notice anything strange? That is **invalid HTML** dear

Comment: You are right, however, the fullscreen check mark not updating is still an active issue.